# Grouping two lines inside align environment to put something to their left

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, align, amsmath

I have an equation which is alligned at 1st equal sign like this:

```
\begin{align}
a &= b + c \nonumber\\ 
d &= e + f \label{eq1}\\    %this is row 1
g &= h + i \nonumber\\      %this is row 2
j &= k + l \nonumber\\
m &= n + o \nonumber
\end{align}
```

How can I group **row 1** and **row 2** so I can put something on the left side of them? I'll be more specific about this. I have constructed an arrow using TiKz like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0.80) coordinate(c1)
(-0.32,0.65) coordinate(c2)
(-0.32,0.25) coordinate(c3)
(0.0,0) coordinate(c4)
(-0.32,0.4) coordinate(c5);
\draw [-latex] (c1) .. controls (c2) and (c3) .. (c4);
\draw (c5) node [anchor=east] {\scriptsize \text{\eqref{eq1}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It looks like this on the paper by itself:

[image]

Now I want to move this element to the left of rows **row 1** and **row 2**. What I am striving to is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify? Are you trying to group two rows of align environment? There are simpler solutions to that! Why do you need to arrow thing, if all you need is grouping them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `remember picture` and `overlay` TikZ methods to mark points and connect them with a `tikzpicture` later on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{math atom}=[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,baseline=0,anchor=base]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[math atom] (a) {$a$};}\;
  &= b + c \nonumber\\ 
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[math atom] (d) {$d$};}\;
  &= e + f \label{eq1}\\    %this is row 1
g &= h + i \nonumber\\      %this is row 2
j &= k + l \nonumber\\
m &= n + o \nonumber
\end{align}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw [-latex] (a) .. controls ([xshift=-0.5cm]a) and ([xshift=-0.5cm]d) .. (d)
  node [midway,anchor=east] {\scriptsize \text{\eqref{eq1}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

This requires two runs of LaTeX to position the coordinates in the right place, but you need two runs to get the cross-references right anyway.

Comment: What is a role of this line: `\tikzstyle{math atom}=[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,baseline=0,anchor=base]`?

Comment: Why not `tikzmark`?

Comment: @71GA: If you comment out `inner sep` and `outer sep`, you'll see that the arrow got "pushed out" to the left. These two keys are used to specify the separation space between the text and the node border (`inner sep`) and that between the border and the anchors (`outer sep`, actually I'm not 100% sure about this one). I don't think `baseline=0` is necessary, because the default is `0pt` anyway. `anchor` controls the vertical alignment of the node--if you comment it out, you'll see that the letters are shifted down.

Comment: I tried this and i love this solution as it is very universal, but it happens sometimes that Berziers cant be drawn and i get blank space. Why is that? Can you explain what does a baseline do?

Comment: @Ryan: one could use tikzmark.  I used a roll-my-own version of tikzmark but didn't like the arrows coming out/going into the southwest corner of the letters.  So I decided to make the left-hand side of the equation a node.

Answer (score 2):

You can just put the TikZ picture in the `align`, but smashing it, so it does not consume vertical space.

```
\begin{align}
a &= b + c \nonumber\\
d &= e + f \label{eq1}\\    %this is row 1
\smash{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0.80) coordinate(c1)
(-0.32,0.65) coordinate(c2)
(-0.32,0.25) coordinate(c3)
(0.0,0) coordinate(c4)
(-0.32,0.4) coordinate(c5);
\draw [-latex] (c1) .. controls (c2) and (c3) .. (c4);
\draw (c5) node [anchor=east] {\scriptsize \text{\eqref{eq1}}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}\ %% here is some horizontal space
g &= h + i \nonumber\\      %this is row 2
j &= k + l \nonumber\\
m &= n + o \nonumber
\end{align}%
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: This is a very simple idea.

Comment: +1 for the idea, but -1 again for using arbitrary numbers in the coordinates.

Comment: @RyanReich I took the OP's code, with its coordinates. I just pasted it into the `align`, `\smash`, be done. But of course a more robust solution with `tikzmark` is preferable.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I hadn't really looked at their code.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know [`tkz-linknodes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-linknodes)? It does something similar to what you want, except links are on the right side and squared. It's based on `TiKZ` and its `remember picture`, so you need two runs to get the correct result.

Next it's a simple example, although I suggest to look at its [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-linknodes/doc/tkz-linknodes-screen.pdf) to see if its worth to try it.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tkz-linknodes}
\begin{document}
\begin{NodesList}
\begin{align}
a &= b + c \nonumber\\ 
d &= e + f \label{eq1} \AddNode \\    %this is row 1
g &= h + i \nonumber \AddNode \\      %this is row 2
j &= k + l \nonumber\\
m &= n + o \nonumber
\end{align}
\LinkNodes{\scriptsize \text{\eqref{eq1}}}
\end{NodesList}
\end{document}
```

[image]